# How to add dynamic SQL dataset to SSRS 2008?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 and am trying to add the following dataset to my report.  However, whether I add this as a stored procedure or text, it does not display any fields after adding it.  And there are no error messages.  What could the workarounds and causes be?  I have 6 report parameters (in this order):

```
@END_YEAR VARCHAR(10), @END_MONTH VARCHAR(10), @END_WEEK VARCHAR(10), @TheTYPE VARCHAR(MAX), @IssueType VARCHAR(MAX), @Manager VARCHAR(MAX)
```

I did make sure these parameters were linked up properly to my stored proc.  I was able to add other datasets of mine which were not dynamic SQL for this same report.  And my stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ActionMetricsPageData
--DECLARE 
@END_YEAR VARCHAR(10),
@END_MONTH VARCHAR(10),
@END_WEEK VARCHAR(10),
@TheTYPE VARCHAR(MAX), @IssueType VARCHAR(MAX), @Manager VARCHAR(MAX)
--SET @TheTYPE = 'All'
--SET @IssueType = '1'
--SET @Manager = 'All'
--AS

DECLARE @MainSQL VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME
DECLARE @END_DATE DATETIME

IF @END_WEEK = '0' AND @END_MONTH = '12'
BEGIN
SET @START_DATE = CAST(('1/1/' + @END_YEAR) AS DATETIME)
SET @END_YEAR = CAST((CAST(@END_YEAR AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))
SET @END_DATE = CAST(('1/1/' + (@END_YEAR)) AS DATETIME)
END
IF @END_WEEK = '0' AND @END_MONTH <> '12'
BEGIN
SET @END_MONTH = CAST((CAST(@END_MONTH AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))
SET @END_DATE = CAST(((@END_MONTH) + '/1/' + @END_YEAR) AS DATETIME)
END

IF @END_WEEK <> '0'
BEGIN
SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(wk, @END_WEEK - 1, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,Convert(varchar(4), @END_YEAR) + '-01-01'), 0)))
SET @END_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @START_DATE)
END

IF @TheTYPE = 'All'
SET @TheTYPE = ' (IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''Correction'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''Corrective'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''Preventive'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Corrective'' OR 
IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Correction'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Preventive'' ) '
ELSE IF @TheTYPE = 'Corrective and Preventive'
SET @TheTYPE = ' (IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''Corrective'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''Preventive'') '
ELSE IF @TheTYPE = 'All QSI'
SET @TheTYPE = ' (IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Corrective'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Correction'' OR IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ''QSI - Preventive'') '
ELSE 
SET @TheTYPE = ' (IAT_PLAN_TYPE = ' + @TheTYPE + ') '

IF @IssueType = '1'
SET @IssueType = ' (QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Correction (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Corrective Action/Preventive Action'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Corrective | Preventive Action (8.1)'' OR 
QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Investigation (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Root Cause Investigation (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Audit'' OR 
QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Supplier Corrective | Preventive Action (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''PXP_PROCESS_QXP'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''PXP_PRODUCT_QXP'') '
ELSE IF @IssueType = '2'
SET @IssueType = ' (QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Audit'') '
ELSE IF @IssueType = '3'
SET @IssueType = ' (QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Correction (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Corrective Action/Preventive Action'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Corrective | Preventive Action (8.1)'' OR 
QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Investigation (8.1)'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Root Cause Investigation (8.1)'') '
ELSE IF @IssueType = '4'
SET @IssueType = ' (QEI_ITY_NAME = ''PXP_PROCESS_QXP'' OR QEI_ITY_NAME = ''PXP_PRODUCT_QXP'') '
ELSE IF @IssueType = '5'
SET @IssueType = ' (QEI_ITY_NAME = ''Supplier Corrective | Preventive Action (8.1)'') '

IF @Manager = 'All'
SET @Manager = ' <> ''All'' '
ELSE 
SET @Manager = '= '' REPLACE(''' + @Manager + ''','','''') '
--SELECT @Manager

SET @MainSQL =
'SELECT DISTINCT IAT_ID, DOC_DOCUMENT_NO, SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE, BTK_NAME, BTK_CLOSED_DATE, TSK_ANT_COMPL_DATE, IAT_PLAN_TYPE, ACT_MANAGER_NAME, QEI_ITY_NAME FROM  
(SELECT SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.IAT_ID, SMARTSOLVE.V_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.DOC_DOCUMENT_NO,  
CASE VH_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_ITY_NAME WHEN ''Audit'' THEN  
(SELECT TOP (1) SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE FROM SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK INNER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK ON SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK.RVW_SGN_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SGN_id  
WHERE (SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK.RVW_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.STK_CURRENT_REV_id)  
ORDER BY SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE DESC) ELSE [PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE END AS SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE, SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.BTK_NAME,  
SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.BTK_CLOSED_DATE, SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.TSK_ANT_COMPL_DATE, SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.IAT_PLAN_TYPE, SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON.ACT_MANAGER_NAME, SMARTSOLVE.VH_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_ITY_NAME  
FROM SMARTSOLVE.VH_QEI_QEX_ISSUE INNER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_QEI_QEX_ISSUE ON SMARTSOLVE.VH_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_id INNER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK ON  
SMARTSOLVE.V_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.BTK_DOC_id LEFT OUTER JOIN  
[PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL ON SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.STK_CURRENT_REV_id = [PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL.RVW_id INNER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK ON  
SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.IMT_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.BTK_PARENT_id LEFT OUTER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON ON SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.BTK_OWNER_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON.ACT_id  
WHERE (SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.BTK_STATUS <> ''ABR'')  
AND (CASE VH_QEI_QEX_ISSUE.QEI_ITY_NAME WHEN ''Audit'' THEN  
(SELECT TOP (1) SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE FROM SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK INNER JOIN  
SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK ON SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK.RVW_SGN_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SGN_id  
WHERE (SMARTSOLVE.V_RVW_REVIEW_TSK.RVW_id = SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.STK_CURRENT_REV_id)
AND [PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE >= @START_DATE AND [PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE < @END_DATE

ORDER BY SMARTSOLVE.V_SGD_SIG_DETAIL_TSK.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE DESC) ELSE [PROC].FINAL_APPROVAL.SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE END IS NOT NULL)  
AND (SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.BTK_NAME <> ''PQRE and /or Action Plan'') AND (SMARTSOLVE.V_IMT_IMPLEMENT_TSK.BTK_NAME <> ''Implement Required Actions'') AND  
(SMARTSOLVE.V_IAT_IMPL_ACTPLAN_TASK.IAT_PLAN_TYPE <> ''Effectivity Check'')  
UNION  
    SELECT SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_ID, SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO, SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_CREATED_DATE,  
      SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_XRS_DESCRIPTION, SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_CLOSED_DATE, NULL, SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_XRS_DESCRIPTION,  
     SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON.ACT_MANAGER_NAME, SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION  
       FROM SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION INNER JOIN  
       SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON ON  
     SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_CLOSED_BY = SMARTSOLVE.V_PSN_PERSON.ACT_LOGONUSER  
       WHERE (SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_XRS_DESCRIPTION = ''Correction'') AND  
    (SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_RESOLUTION <> ''300'')  
)B 
WHERE '

SET @MainSQL = @MainSQL + @TheTYPE + ' AND ' + @IssueType + ' AND ACT_MANAGER_NAME ' + @Manager
EXEC (@MainSQL)
```

Comment: It would sure help if you could put all of that into code blocks.

Comment: What happens when you try to call the stored procedure from Management Studio?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion board, don't post answers unless you're actually answering. Use the commenting system for comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the query execution of the report in sql profiler after click on refreshing field button of the dataset property.